# peerjs call.on("stream", not working on iOS

Tags: node.js, websocket, stream, peerjs

I have a video calling application that I wrote with nodejs webrtc. It works fine on windows and androids, but it doesn't work on apple ios phones when I follow the ancestor

```
call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        socket.emit("join-pper", userVideoStream);
         addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
       });
```

Why is this function not working?
the full code is below

Comment: Looks like the answer you posted the additional code as an answer. You should move that into the question if that is the correct place for it.

Comment: can you share how implement peerjs in swift

Answer (score 0):

```
navigator.mediaDevices
  .getUserMedia({
    audio: true,
    video: false,
  })
  .then((stream) => {
    myVideoStream = stream;
    addVideoStream(myVideo, stream);

    peer.on("call", (call) => {
      
      call.answer(stream);
      const video = document.createElement("video");
      call.on("stream", (userVideoStream) => {
        socket.emit("join-pper", userVideoStream);
        addVideoStream(video, userVideoStream);
      });
    });

    socket.on("user-connected", (userId) => {
      connectToNewUser(userId, stream);
    });
  });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).